# what is the indenting tag in html?

Tags: html, css, indentation

I want to indent my text for a website I am making in html. I don't want to keep typing `&nsbp;` four times. I know there is a way to do this, but I'm not sure how. Thanks!

Comment: This is a job for CSS rather than HTML.

Comment: I've Googled `how to indent text in html` and there's the answer, **I'm 200% sure you did the same**, so... What's the question about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just looking to indent the first line, it's

```
 p { 
   text-indent: 4em; /* or 15px, or 5%, 2rem or 3vw */
 }
```

You could easily apply this to a div or whatever you want.

If you are looking to indent all lines, you of course will want `padding-left: 4em;`

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways to indent text in html. Here are a few that come to mind:

```
<blockquote>test</blockquote>

<p style="margin-left: 15px;">text</p>

<p style="text-indent: 15px;">Only first line</p>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text

<pre>  text</pre>

<ul style="list-style: none;"><li>text</li>

<table width="100"><td></td><td>Ewww</td></table>

<dl><dd>text</dd></dl>

<span style="width: 10px; display: hidden;"></span><span>text</span>
```

You can see the result at: http://jsfiddle.net/2My4b/5/

Answer (score 0):

[`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) can indent the first line of text, in a paragraph or a div.

It can be used like this:

```
<element selector> {
  text-indent: <how much>;
}
```

If you want to indent all lines, use [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding), like this:

```
<element selector> {
  padding: <how much>;
}
```